# values not updating from PHP AJAX form to MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Hi all and thanks in advance to all for this

I tired searching the entire forum and was unable to find the answer i was looking for so i decided to post a new thread, if a thread explaining this already exists than i'm sorry for not finding it and posting there.

Anyhow my problem is that i am unable to update the values enterd in the form. I have attached all the files i'm using to try get this to work. What happens is that i'm able to enter and delete records from `MYSQL database` using the `ajax` and `PHP`, but i am not able to update even though after checking the php file.

pls find the link were complete files are zipped

http://cid-b88405bc51ef157b.skydrive.live.com/browse.aspx/Public?lc=1033

Comment: try running the backend directly instead of calling it through ajax. This makes it easier to debug.

Comment: But the thing i require is a non refrishing page... and as per your suggestion i had sone it but it not working... if you can you please post the code i would be greatfull to you.. as i am bit dull in ajax programming

Comment: Which of the PHP files are you launching in your browser that is not working?

Comment: update.php  is the PHP file where i tried to launch in internet explorer 8 browser and i had even tried in firefox also... but as explained i am able to see the update form in which i can enter the data but unable to post it into MYSQL database.
as per my knowledge there is a an error in update.php where i am unable to find it out..
can you please look into my files so that it will be clear to understand

Answer (score 1):

**Your problem could be present in couple places:**

1. incorrect call to ajax
2. incorrect parameter parsing in ajax
3. incorrect update statement

**What you need to do:**

1. Make sure that you passing correct parameters
2. Make sure that you parse those parameters correctly
3. Debug your update statement and make sure that it is working