# I am not able to update form data to MySQL using PHP and jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

What happens is that I'm able to add and delete records from form using jQuery and PHP scripts to MYSQL database, but I am not able to update data which was retrieved from the database. The file structure is as follows:

index.php is a file with jQuery functions where it displays form for adding new data to MYSQL using save.php file and list of all records are view without refreshing page (calling load-list.php to view all records from index.php works fine, and save.php to save data from form)

-> Delete is an function called from index.php to delete record from MySQL database (function calling delete.php works fine)

-> Update is an function called from index.php to update data using update-form.php by retriving specific record from MySQL table, (works fine)

> Problem lies in updating data from
>   update-form.php to update.php (in
>   which update query is written for
>   MySQL)

I have tried in many ways - at last I had figured out that data is not being transferred from update-form.php to update.php; there is a small problem in jQuery AJAX function where it is not transferring data to update.php page. Something is missing in calling update.php page it is not entering into that page.

Please find the link below to download all files which is of 35kb (virus free assurance):

[download mysmallform files in ZIPped format, including mysql query](http://cid-b88405bc51ef157b.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/Public/mysmallform.zip)

---

```
<pre>
<body>
<div class="container">  
    <form id="submit" method="post">  
        <fieldset>  
            <legend>Enter Information</legend>  
            <label for="Name">Name    : </label>  
        <input id="name" class="text" name="name" size="20" type="text">
            <label for="gender">Gender : </label>  
            <input id="gender" class="text" name="gender" size="20" type="text">
            <label for="dob">DoB     : </label>  
            <input id="dob" class="date" name="dob" size="20" type="text">  <button> Add  </button>  
        </fieldset>
    </form>  
    <div class="name_list"></div>
    <div class="update_form"></div>  
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    function loadList(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "load-list.php",
            cache: false,
            success : function(html){
                $(".name_list").html(html);
            }
        });
    }
    loadList();

    $("form#submit").submit(function() {
        // we want to store the values from the form input box, then send via ajax below
        var x=window.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item?")
        var name = $('#name').attr('value');
        var gender = $('#gender').attr('value');
        var dob = $('#dob').attr('value');
        if (x==true){
                     $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "save.php",
                data: "name="+ name +"& gender="+ gender +"& dob="+ dob,
                success: function(){
                    loadList();
                               }
                 });
                 }
        return false;
    });

    $(".delete_button").live("click", function(){
        //this deletes the row clicked on with an alert and then reloads the list
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var x=window.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item?")
        if (x==true){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "delete.php",
                data: "id="+ id,
                success: function(){
                    loadList();
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });

    $(".update_button").live("click", function(){
        //this loads the update form
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        $.ajax({
            url: "update-form.php",
            data: "id="+ id,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
                $(".update_form").html(html);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

      $("#updateform").ajaxform("submit",function(){
    //$("form#update").live("submit",(function() {
    // we want to send via ajax and empty the html from the update_form element
        var name = $('#name_update').attr('value');
        var gender = $('#gender_update').attr('value');
        var dob = $('#dob_update').attr('value');
        var id = $('#id').attr('value');
        alert (name);
            $.ajax({

                url: "update.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: "name="+ name +"& gender="+ gender +"& dob="+ dob,
                error: function(){
                    alert('Error loading document');
                             },
                success: function(){
                alert (" i  am  in success below load list ");
                    $(".update_form").empty();
                    loadList();

                        }

            });
        return false;
    });
});
</script> </body>
</pre>
```

Comment: Best putting the code here, not in a zip file.

Comment: duplicates
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578172/data-not-transfred-from-form-to-mysql-table-updating-of-data-is-not-happening http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476816/help-please-values-not-updating-from-php-ajax-form-to-mysql-database

Comment: Sheesh, there's a lot of hate for newbies here lately.

Comment: We need a new close reason: "Help vampire" (http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/). @Jimson: Please do not ask the same question over and over.

Comment: @Alan: It's not hate when the OP doesn't help out very much.  It's just not a good question.  Nothing personal.

Comment: if you think it's not a good question, then do not reply on it. i dont get the negative votes just for the reason that "you" don't like the question. and then they say "nothing personal".

Comment: Locate the problem and paste the code that may cause the problem?

Comment: @pinaki: I think the OP could have done a much better job of trying to communicate the problem to the people he expects to help him. Judging from the fact that the single current answer to this question is from a person who admits to not even looking at the OP's code, I don't see how you can honestly disagree.  Why have the option of a downvote if it's unethical to use it?

Comment: my disagreement is based on the fact that the asker is a noob and it is not as if he has laid down his terms to the community or disagreed to change. in my opinion the option of a downvote is only for the scenario when the person behaves unreasonable and being newbie is not unreasonable. The "smarter" people here can ask for what they need and if they think it is not worth the effort, then leave the question alone.

Comment: also, yes i agree he did a bad job explaining the situation but i dont see how he cant get better given a little assistance. or atleast he can do without the downvotes

Comment: @col shrapnel - you won't even see my downvote here. and there is no crown here to teach, just some arrogant bullies, who think that since they came first to SO, the site belongs to them.

Comment: Sir... please cool down for gods sake... i ask forgiveness to all i am wrong in any way..sir once my problem is solved i might go away but you people stay here so sir dont argue for my sake if any one helps me that would be a greate help for as well as to all becuase all not that genius!!! one might help many in many other ways thank you once again

Comment: @chris a year ago people would have tried to tease a better question out of the op. Thease days it's drive by down votes and maybe a condescending comment

Comment: Hey @Jimson you just took this site wrong. This site is not for solving problems. Nothing personal. To solve your problem you have to learn to program. This site cant' learn programming for you.

Comment: okay, so "this" site is "not for solving problems". i am enlightened. a site where people ask hundreds of questions everyday (including basic echo problems), and get their answers is suddenly not for solving problems. whatever.

Comment: Yes sir Mr. pinaki i do agree with you.. if this site is not for solving then can i question to all the members of this site. why are all here and what does badges ment for??? 
i dont want to hurt with these comments but at the least "i want to learn for now for what all are here for??"

Comment: i do agree sir solving does not mean that all are hitting their heads for cracking problem. at the least i was asking for help to find the loop to rectify my self in the script.. this is as simple as that". So as if any other person comes with the same issue this might help him in many ways... i never ment or mean for giving me a long chained examples..

Comment: @col shrapnel. please note that the FAQ says "of interest to other programmers", not "of interest to ALL programmers". what you might deem unimportant can be good stuff for a noob. Also, everyone here, including the asker, agrees that the first question was wrongly asked. The simple reason being that he is new to the site. Also, he has shown the tendency to change the question format once explained. what i don't understand is the urgency of awarding negative votes.

Comment: You see, the OP should not just say help me. He should identify his problem first. Find out what he wants to do so he can ask: "Why am I getting this database error: xyz" for example. Not "My app doesn't work! Why?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copy-pasted your code into a php file and get a "$ is not defined" error in javascript. I look at your code tells me that you have not included the jquery file. Try using firefox as the browser and firebug for debugger to avoid such minor issues.

Comment: Yes this has worked! Thanks a lot. i am sorry for delayed response.

Answer (score 1):

You know, JQuery also has a post function. Nothing wrong with using normal html to handle requests. Not everything must be run through listeners.

```
function updateQuery(){

    var name = $('#name_update').attr('value');
    var gender = $('#gender_update').attr('value');
    var dob = $('#dob_update').attr('value');

    $.post('update.php', { name:name, gender:gender, dob:dob }, function(data){
        if(data == 'success')
            {
                $(".update_form").empty();
                loadList();

            }
            else
            {
                alert('fail');
            }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

sometimes jquery does not like single variable $.post requests. have you tried passing a second null variable?

I have not looked at your code. If add and delete work, then update should also unless you're overlooking something obvious or you're just falling for the same single variable garbage I had happen.

Comment: but sir can you suggest or guide me to complete this, is there any way to get my work done... please sir

Comment: @Jimson, Are you the OP? Stop whining and start programming: http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/hacker-howto.html

Comment: please note that i am not insisting you, as per my knowledge i am just asking help for this. I am extremely sorry if i hurt you with my english. Any way Mr.pinaki helped me to solve this issue. Thank you very much.